# Query for how to add the missing dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

need to know how to add the date missing with null data in the corresponding field

```
**05/28/2012    NULL
05/29/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  Break In
05/30/2012  Break Out
05/31/2012  NULL**

06/03/2012  NULL
06/03/2012  Break In
06/03/2012  Break Out
06/03/2012  In Duty
06/03/2012  Out Duty
06/04/2012  NULL
06/04/2012  In Duty
06/04/2012  Out Duty
06/05/2012  NULL
06/05/2012  Break In
06/05/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  NULL
06/06/2012  Break In
06/06/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  In Duty
06/06/2012  Out Duty
06/07/2012  NULL
06/07/2012  In Duty
06/07/2012  Out Duty

06/10/2012  NULL
06/10/2012  Break Out
06/10/2012  In Duty
06/10/2012  Out Duty
06/11/2012  NULL
06/11/2012  In Duty
06/11/2012  Out Duty
06/12/2012  NULL
06/13/2012  NULL
06/14/2012  NULL
```

The result that I need is like:

```
05/28/2012  NULL
05/29/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  Break In
05/30/2012  Break Out
05/31/2012  NULL
06/01/2012      null
06/02/2012      null
06/03/2012  NULL
06/03/2012  Break In
06/03/2012  Break Out
06/03/2012  In Duty
06/03/2012  Out Duty
06/04/2012  NULL
06/04/2012  In Duty
06/04/2012  Out Duty
06/05/2012  NULL
06/05/2012  Break In
06/05/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  NULL
06/06/2012  Break In
06/06/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  In Duty
06/06/2012  Out Duty
06/07/2012  NULL
06/07/2012  In Duty
06/07/2012  Out Duty
06/08/2012      null
06/09/2012      null
06/10/2012  NULL
06/10/2012  Break Out
06/10/2012  In Duty
06/10/2012  Out Duty
06/11/2012  NULL
06/11/2012  In Duty
06/11/2012  Out Duty
06/12/2012  NULL
06/13/2012  NULL
06/14/2012  NULL
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) please post a working query, does not matter is incorrect, at least is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form a Date Calender with a start and end date range and perform a left join with your table to get the needed result.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Dt Datetime, Value VARCHAR(20) NULL)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('05/28/2012',NULL),
('05/29/2012',NULL),
('05/30/2012',NULL),('05/30/2012','Break In'),('05/30/2012','Break Out'),
('05/31/2012',NULL),
('06/03/2012',NULL),('06/03/2012','Break In'),('06/03/2012','Break Out'),('06/03/2012','In Duty'),('06/03/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/04/2012',NULL),('06/04/2012','In Duty'),('06/04/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/05/2012',NULL),('06/05/2012','Break In'),('06/05/2012','Break Out'),
('06/06/2012',NULL),('06/06/2012','Break In'),('06/06/2012','Break Out'),('06/06/2012','In Duty'),('06/06/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/07/2012',NULL),('06/07/2012','In Duty'),('06/07/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/10/2012',NULL),('06/10/2012','Break Out'),('06/10/2012','In Duty'),('06/10/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/11/2012',NULL),('06/11/2012','In Duty'),('06/11/2012','Out Duty'),
('06/12/2012',NULL),
('06/13/2012',NULL),
('06/14/2012',NULL)


DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '2012-05-28', @endDate = '2012-06-14' --yyyy-mm-dd
;WITH Calender AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT 
    [Date] = Convert(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,101)
    ,Value
FROM Calender c
LEFT JOIN @t t 
ON t.Dt = c.CalanderDate
```

**Result**

```
Date    Value
05/28/2012  NULL
05/29/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  NULL
05/30/2012  Break In
05/30/2012  Break Out
05/31/2012  NULL
06/01/2012  NULL
06/02/2012  NULL
06/03/2012  NULL
06/03/2012  Break In
06/03/2012  Break Out
06/03/2012  In Duty
06/03/2012  Out Duty
06/04/2012  NULL
06/04/2012  In Duty
06/04/2012  Out Duty
06/05/2012  NULL
06/05/2012  Break In
06/05/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  NULL
06/06/2012  Break In
06/06/2012  Break Out
06/06/2012  In Duty
06/06/2012  Out Duty
06/07/2012  NULL
06/07/2012  In Duty
06/07/2012  Out Duty
06/08/2012  NULL
06/09/2012  NULL
06/10/2012  NULL
06/10/2012  Break Out
06/10/2012  In Duty
06/10/2012  Out Duty
06/11/2012  NULL
06/11/2012  In Duty
06/11/2012  Out Duty
06/12/2012  NULL
06/13/2012  NULL
06/14/2012  NULL
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir if there is one more coloum with name Event and with the case i was able to add the event but was unable to add for the newly added data

Answer (score 5):

Best option is to keep a calender table which contains all the dates for some years that you want to calculate and then left join with that table

```
select date,col1
from calender_table c
left join 
your_table t
on c.[date]=t.[date]
```

You could create a calender table very easily. There are lots of scripts available in the net.
[click for examples](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @stDate datetime='05/28/2012'
declare @eddate datetime='06/14/2012'
select DATEADD(day,number,@stdate) from master..spt_values where type='P'
and DATEADD(day,number,@stdate) <= @eddate
```

Here just join this result with your table on dates column to get the missing dates