# SQL of a daterange without empty spaces

Tags: sql, date, diagram, mysql5

I need to generate a diagram out of data from a table. This table has the following date:

```
Timestamp | Value
01-20-2013| 5
01-21-2013| 7
01-22-2013| 3
01-25-2013| 5
```

As you can see not every date has a value. If I put that into a diagram it looks weird. Dates are used for the X-axis. As 01-23-2013 and 01-24-2013 is missing this values are either not printed in the diagram (looks weird) or the are printed put the line of the diagram goes from 3 directly to 5 and not to 0 as it should.

Is there a way via SQL to select the data so that it looks like this:

```
Timestamp | Value
01-20-2013| 5
01-21-2013| 7
01-22-2013| 3
01-23-2013| 0
01-24-2013| 0
01-25-2013| 5
```

Any help is appreciated!

Regards,
Alex

Edit: I had no clue that the database engine was that important. This is running on a MySQL 5 Database (not sure about the complete version string).

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: What version of SQL?  Here's a metod for SQL server...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597143/query-for-how-to-add-the-missing-dates-in-sql

Comment: This is a MySQL 5 database. Sorry. I added this info above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, depending on the database.  Date functions are notoriously database independent.

Here is an approach using a "driver" table with all dates and to use this for a left outer join:

```
select driver.timestamp, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct timestamp + n.n as timestamp
      from t cross join
           (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
           )
     ) driver left outer join
     t;
```

This version assumes that there are gaps of no more than three days.

In some databases, you can construct the list of dates using a recursive CTE.  Such an approach would handle gaps of any size.