# SQL Server: Filling in missing dates where each entity has different date ranges

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a data set with multiple entities, each entity having data (reported monthly) for a range of dates.  Each entity has a different start and stop dates.  Each entity can have months where no data is reported.

I need to copy this data to another table, filling in default values for each month an entity does not have data reported within the particular date range for the entity.

My data sets are very large (tens of thousands of entities) with each entity having data each month for several decades.

I have tried initializing the destination table with records for each entity covering a time range that should include the minimum and maximum dates possible for all entities.  Then trimming off non-populated records for each entity at the start and end of its date range.  This generates millions of dummy records that eventually get deleted. This process takes several hours.

I need something much faster.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results for faster response

Comment: Right Join to a table that has all the dates you want to show in your results.   This is a very common solution to a very common problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query for how to add the missing dates in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597143/query-for-how-to-add-the-missing-dates-in-sql)

Comment: can you query for the min(start) and max(end) for each entity, and only enter default values for those months for that entity, instead of entering default values for the min/max of all entities?

Comment: For Beth  -  I can get the min and max date for each entity.  I am not sure how to structure a query to loop through all of the entities and dates.  This would work, but still it seems there should be a query that would fill in the gaps on the fly.

Comment: For Tab -- I am doing a hard join to a table with the full range of dates.  This is slow.  I can try a right join, but I would still need to deal with each entity having its own date range.  I would have to build the right join table with the range of each entity, unless I can filter the dates based upon the range for each entity.  Will have to think about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like having a table full of dates to join on or worry about. I would use a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAllMonths(@Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME)
RETURNS
@AllMonths TABLE
(
MonthStart DATETIME,
NextMonth DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp DATETIME

    IF @Start > @End
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp = @Start
        SET @Start = @End
        SET @End = @Temp
    END

    -- Get first day of the month
    SET @Start = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Start), 0)


    WHILE @Start <= @End
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Start)

        INSERT INTO @AllMonths
        VALUES(@Start, @Temp)

        SET @Start = @Temp
    END

RETURN

END
```

Then you would use it like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.GetAllMonths('4/15/2015', '10/1/2015') m
LEFT JOIN RequestItems r
ON m.MonthStart <=  r.ModifiedDate 
    AND  r.ModifiedDate < m.NextMonth
WHERE r.Id is null  -- to get the missing ones only
```

Comment: I will look at this function.  I still would have to deal with each entity having its own date range.  I would have to loop through all entities, figure out its particular date range and use your function to fill the range for that entity.

Comment: @user1753352  See edit, added the very last line to only get the missing months.