# Insert 3 dates for each row as part of sql select statement

Tags: sql, date, prepared-statement

I have a table - websites and I want to calculate revenue of each website for last 3 days each. This table does not have a date column.

```
select distinct(website_id), cast( GETDATE() AS rundate ) from websites;
```

Result might look like:

```
Website_Id    rundate
5             11-11-2021
7             11-11-2021
```

I use above result to insert in a parameterized sql query which queries the revenue db which looks something like:

```
select total_revenue from revenue where website_id = %{website_id}% and date > %{run_date} and date < DATEADD(day, -1, %{run_date})
```

I want to do this for last 3 days. Is there a way I can get all three dates in the select query on websites? Expected result:

```
Website_Id    rundate
5             11-11-2021
5             10-11-2021
5             09-11-2021
7             11-11-2021
7             10-11-2021
7             09-11-2021
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query for how to add the missing dates in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597143/query-for-how-to-add-the-missing-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to make use of the MAX and GROUP BY functions in SQL.

I think something like the following might work:

```
SELECT Website_ID, MAX(RunDate) FROM websites
Where RunDate <= DATEADD(day,-3,GetDate())
Group By Website_ID
```

Comment: The website does not have a date column. It is just a list of websites

Comment: @russ2000 then I think you might struggle with this. If there is not date to compare against, how can you possibly find the last 3 days from an unknown date? Is there a relative date stored in another table by any chance? And a way to join the two tables together? Is there a separate revenue table with a date in that we can join to the websites table?