# SQL query that returns the percentage of new users per day from table that describe activity

Tags: sql, oracle

My test table looks like this:

| USERID | updated_date |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2023-01-01 |
| 222 | 2023-01-01 |
| 111 | 2023-01-03 |
| 333 | 2023-01-07 |
| 333 | 2023-01-09 |
| 333 | 2023-01-10 |
| ... | ... |

I need an SQL query that returns the percentage increase of new users per day.
The table contains the traffic, so it's possible that a user will not appear in a certain day, but it still exists in the DB and has to accounted for.

The output should look like this:

| Date | total users | percentage of new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | null |
| 2023-01-03 | 2 | 0% |
| 2023-01-07 | 3 | 50% |
| 2023-01-09 | 3 | 0% |
| 2023-01-10 | 3 | 0% |

I tried several queries with DISTINCT, but that's not enough, as a day can pass without an existing user performing any action, so it won't be accounted for.

Comment: and, please, [add a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql#:~:text=and%20a%20tag%20for%20the%20DBMS%20implementation%20(e.g.%20MySQL%2C%20PostgreSQL%2C%20Oracle%2C%20MS%20SQL%20Server%2C%20IBM%20DB2%2C%20etc.)%20being%20used)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query for how to add the missing dates in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597143/query-for-how-to-add-the-missing-dates-in-sql)

Comment: Why 50% new on 2023-01-07? Total 3, where 1 is new, i.e. I'd expect 33%.

Comment: @jarlh - an increase of 50% from 2 is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using analytic functions and case expressions you could have (for every date) columns for previous number of users, number of new users, percentage of new users vs previous - with - total users and percentage of new users vs total:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 111 "USER_ID", DATE '2023-01-01' "UPDATED_DATE" From Dual Union All
          Select 222, DATE '2023-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select 111, DATE '2023-01-03' From Dual Union All
          Select 333, DATE '2023-01-07' From Dual Union All
          Select 333, DATE '2023-01-09' From Dual Union All
          Select 333, DATE '2023-01-10' From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT   A_DATE,  
         Sum(NEW_USERS) Over(Order By A_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding) "PREVIOUS_USERS",
         NEW_USERS,
         NEW_USERS * 100 / Sum(NEW_USERS) Over(Order By A_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding) "NEW_VS_PREVIOUS_PCT",
         Sum(NEW_USERS) Over(Order By A_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "TOTAL_USERS",
         Round(NEW_USERS * 100 / Sum(NEW_USERS) Over(Order By A_DATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row), 2) "NEW_VS_TOTAL_PCT"     
FROM    ( Select    Distinct UPDATED_DATE "A_DATE",
                    Case  When ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By USER_ID Order By UPDATED_DATE) = 1 
                          Then Sum(1) Over(Partition By UPDATED_DATE)
                    Else 0
                    End "NEW_USERS"
          From      tbl
          Order By UPDATED_DATE
         )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_DATE   PREVIOUS_USERS  NEW_USERS NEW_VS_PREVIOUS_PCT TOTAL_USERS NEW_VS_TOTAL_PCT
-------- -------------- ---------- ------------------- ----------- ----------------
01.01.23                         2                               2              100
03.01.23              2          0                   0           2                0
07.01.23              2          1                  50           3            33,33
09.01.23              3          0                   0           3                0
10.01.23              3          0                   0           3                0   */
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use an cte for get the percentage. I used mysql for this solution

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 
        updated_date,
        (select count(distinct userid) 
            from stack t2 where t2.updated_date <= t1.updated_date) total_users
    FROM stack t1
    group by updated_date
)

select 
    updated_date as date, 
    total_users,
    concat(
      cast(
        round(100 * 
          (total_users - lag(total_users,1) over(order by updated_date)) / 
           lag(total_users,1) over(order by updated_date), 2) 
          as signed), 
       '%') as 'percentage of new'
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to number, for each user, the dates in ascending order. Then you need to total the number of users each day where the `update_date` was their first day (i.e. they are a new user) and then you can use an analytic `SUM` to get a running total over the days and use this to find both the total of new users and the percentage of the total number of users that is new:

```sql
SELECT updated_date,
       SUM(new_users) OVER (ORDER BY updated_date) AS total_users,
       new_users / SUM(new_users) OVER (ORDER BY updated_date) * 100
         AS percentage_new
FROM   (
  SELECT updated_date,
         SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new_users
  FROM   (
    SELECT userid,
           updated_date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY updated_date) AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  GROUP BY updated_date
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (USERID, updated_date) AS
SELECT 111, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 222, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, DATE '2023-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 333, DATE '2023-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 333, DATE '2023-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 333, DATE '2023-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| UPDATED_DATE | TOTAL_USERS | PERCENTAGE_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 100 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 | 33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |

If your percentage should be the percentage of users for each day that are new then you can use:

```sql
SELECT updated_date,
       SUM(
         SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ) OVER (ORDER BY updated_date) AS total_users,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
         AS percentage_new_for_day
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         updated_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY updated_date) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
GROUP BY updated_date;
```

Which outputs:

| UPDATED_DATE | TOTAL_USERS | PERCENTAGE_NEW_FOR_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 100 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 | 100 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |

---

If you want the percentage daily increase in the total number of new users (compared to the previous day) then:

```sql
SELECT updated_date,
       SUM(
         SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ) OVER (ORDER BY updated_date) AS total_users,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       / SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
           OVER (
             ORDER BY updated_date
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           )
       * 100
         AS percentage_daily_increase
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         updated_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY updated_date) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
GROUP BY updated_date;
```

Which outputs:

| UPDATED_DATE | TOTAL_USERS | PERCENTAGE_DAILY_INCREASE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | *null* |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 | 50 |
| 2023-01-09 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J28U9O7P)